# how to solve problem with Electron IPC renderer.js not working on v26, and can fetch api at renderer.js without set contextIsolation=true

Tags: node.js, axios, electron

Please help me, I'm still new to Electron. the Electron version I'm using is v26 the latest one.
The problem I face is when to use the "required" at renderer.js and got an error, required is not allowed at renderer.js, I do some research that I need to set contextIsolation = false and nodeIntegration = true and it solves my problem, then the next problem comes when at renderer.js i want use axios to call an API , here the error i get

`because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback`

And to solve that problem i need set contextIsolation = true, which is call back the first problem

I also have try to use IPC but its not working at renderer.js

main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow,ipcMain  } = require('electron')
const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: true,
        nodeIntegration: false,
        allowRunningInsecureContent: false,
        allowDisplayingInsecureContent: false,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      }
    })
    win.loadFile('index.html')
      // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  ipcMain.on('make-http-request', async (event, url) => {
    try {
      // Use Axios to make an HTTP GET request
      // Send the response data back to the renderer process
      event.sender.send('http-request-response', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors here if necessary
      event.sender.send('http-request-response', { error: error.message });
    }
  });
}
```

preload.js

```js
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require('electron');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "electron",
    {
      ipcRenderer: ipcRenderer
    }
  );
})
```

renderer.js

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const ipcRenderer = window.electron.ipcRenderer
    const sendMessageButton = document.getElementById('sendMessage');
    const responseDiv = document.getElementById('response');


    sendMessageButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
        ipcRenderer.send('make-http-request', 'https://...');
    
        ipcRenderer.on('http-request-response', (event, data) => {
            responseDiv.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        });
    });
})
```

index.html

```html
<button id="sendMessage">Send Message to Main Process</button>
    <div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: Saying "its not working" is not helpful. What is not working? What's happening? What errors? You should read about [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security) and follow the [IPC docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc). Your current code exposes the whole ipcRenderer API, which is [unsecure](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations).